# How to check to see which value of a list is highest another another list

Tags: java, list

This is my situation: I have list A of values. I also have list B which contains a hierarchy of ranks. The first being of the highest, last being of the lowest. List A will contain one, some, or all of the values from list B. I want to see which value from list A is of the highest degree (or lowest index) on list B. How would I do this best?

Just in case its still unclear, this is an example:

```
List A: Merchant, Peasant, Queen
List B: King, Queen, Knight, Merchant, Peasant
```

I'd want the method to spit out Queen in this case

Comment: Take a look at [List.indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))

Comment: You can go through list `B` from top to bottom and stop as soon as you find a value that is present in the `A` list.

Comment: @ChadDienhart I tried to lookup the indexes of each element of list A in list B but then the problem is how to compare them in an efficient manner. I feel like there's no way other than create a bunch of unnecessary objects which I'd like to avoid

Comment: @Titus Actually thats a smart idea. If you post it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it

Comment: I think I will be more helpful to you by letting you try to do this yourself.

Comment: @Titus I meant just the concept. But thanks for your help

Comment: A very short solution would be one using streams e.g. `a.stream().min((x,y) -> b.indexOf(x) - b.indexOf(y))`

Comment: @Reimeus Additionally, I'm not really sure why you think I'm doing my homework. I'm simply self-learning and ran into a problem that I didn't see a solution to, and I proceeded to utilize the stackoverflow community. I feel that's exactly what its meant for and don't really see why you felt the need to  challenge me.

Comment: @AllenF. It's because you didn't show _your_ attempt to do the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming List B is already sorted from Top Rank -> Bottom rank, one arbitary way you could solve it is with

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] firstList = { "Merchant", "Peasant", "Queen" };
    String[] secondList = { "King", "Queen", "Knight", "Merchant", "Peasant" };

    for (String highRank : secondList) {
        for (String lowRank : firstList) {
            if (highRank.equalsIgnoreCase(lowRank)) {
                System.out.println(highRank);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called a "[partial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)", and the proper way to implement the behavior you're looking for in Java is with a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that defines the ordering; something like:

```
public class PartialOrdering<T> implements Comparator<T> {
  private final Map<T, Integer> listPositions = new HashMap<>();

  public PartialOrdering(List<T> elements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
      listPositions.put(elements.get(i), i);
    }
  }

  public int compare(T a, T b) {
    Integer aPos = listPositions.get(a);
    Integer bPos = listPositions.get(b);
    if (aPos == null || bPos == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "PartialOrdering can only compare elements it's aware of.");
    }
    return Integer.compare(aPos, bPos);
  }
}
```

You can then simply call [`Collections.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) to find the largest value in your first list.

This is *much* more efficient than either of the other answers, which are both O(n^2) and don't handle unknown elements coherently (they assume we have a total ordering).

---

Even better than implementing your own `PartialOrdering`, however, is to use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Ordering`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class, which provides an [efficient partial ordering](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit(java.util.List)) and a number of other useful tools. With Guava all you need to do is:

```
// Or store the result of Ordering.explicit() if you need to reuse it
Ordering.explicit(listB).max(listA);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work give it a Try:

```
function int getHighest(List<String> listA, List<String> listB)
{
int index = 0;
int max = 100;
int tmpMax = 0;
for(String test:lista)
{
    for(int i =0;i<listb.size();++i)
    {
        if(list.get(i).equals(test))
        {
            tmpMax = index;
        }

    }
    if(tmpMax < max) max = tmpMax;
    ++index;
}



return max;
}
```